# Gate io error INVALID_SIGNATURE in app script

Tags: javascript, json, api, google-apps-script

I try to get data from Exchange Gate.io by app script.
This is my code:

```
function data() {
var key = "***"
var sec = "***"
var timestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)

var base = "https://api.gateio.ws";
var prefix = "/api/v4"
var pat = '/wallet/total_balance'

var sign = "timestamp=" + timestamp;

Logger.log(sign)


  var signature = Utilities.computeHmacSignature(Utilities.MacAlgorithm.HMAC_SHA_512, sign, sec);
  signature = signature.map(function(e) {
    var v = (e < 0 ? e + 256 : e).toString(16);
    return v.length == 1 ? "0" + v : v;
}).join("");
 

    var params = {
        'method': "get",
        'headers': {
                      'Accept': 'application/json', 
                      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                       'KEY': key, 
                       'Timestamp': timestamp,
                       'SIGN': signature,
                       
                      },
        'muteHttpExceptions': true,
    };

   var data = UrlFetchApp.fetch(base + prefix + pat, headers=params);
   Logger.log(data)

}
```

I get the error:

```
{"label":"INVALID_SIGNATURE","message":"Signature mismatch"}
```

The Keys is valid problem in code.

to learn more check that: https://www.gate.io/docs/apiv4/en/#retrieve-user-s-total-balances

Comment: When I access your provided URL, the status code 404 occurs. By this, I cannot see the official document.

Comment: some time give same error refresh or go from google,  googling for gate API v4 /wallet/total balance. this is the main URL page https://www.gate.io/docs/apiv4/en/

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, when I searched it, I could find the official document. So, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: it's work. I try to add another method like that: https://www.gate.io/docs/developers/apiv4/en/#list-orders . I add everything to get open orders: `query_param = 'currency_pair=BTC_USDT&status=open'` work fine but if I try to get finished give me empty [] `query_param = 'currency_pair=BTC_USDT&status=finished'` . note I have a orders finished in  this currency_pair. I thing need to add another parameter if add finished but can't find it.

Comment: @Tanaike I add new question is this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72363674/gate-exchange-cant-get-orders-using-app-script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the official document, when I directly access the URL, an error occurs. But, when I search it on Google and access it, I could open the document. From the document, I found the documentation for the authorization and the document for "Retrieve user's total balances". And also, I found the following sample python script from the official document.

```
import time
import hashlib
import hmac
import requests

def gen_sign(method, url, query_string=None, payload_string=None):
    key = ''        # api_key
    secret = ''     # api_secret

    t = time.time()
    m = hashlib.sha512()
    m.update((payload_string or "").encode('utf-8'))
    hashed_payload = m.hexdigest()
    s = '%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s' % (method, url, query_string or "", hashed_payload, t)
    sign = hmac.new(secret.encode('utf-8'), s.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()
    return {'KEY': key, 'Timestamp': str(t), 'SIGN': sign}

host = "https://api.gateio.ws"
prefix = "/api/v4"
headers = {'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

url = '/wallet/total_balance'
query_param = ''
# for `gen_sign` implementation, refer to section `Authentication` above
sign_headers = gen_sign('GET', prefix + url, query_param)
headers.update(sign_headers)
r = requests.request('GET', host + prefix + url, headers=headers)
print(r.json())
```

In your situation, when this script is converted to Google Apps Script, I thought that it is your goal. When this python script is converted to Google Apps Script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, please set the variables of `key` and `secret`.

```js
function gen_sign_(key, secret, method, url, query_param = "", payload_string = "") {
  const t = (Date.now() / 1000).toString();
  const c1 = Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.SHA_512, payload_string, Utilities.Charset.UTF_8);
  const c2 = Utilities.formatString('%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s', method, url, query_param, c1.map(b => ("0" + (b < 0 && b + 256 || b).toString(16)).slice(-2)).join(""), t);
  const c3 = Utilities.computeHmacSignature(Utilities.MacAlgorithm.HMAC_SHA_512, c2, secret, Utilities.Charset.UTF_8);
  const sign = c3.map(b => ("0" + (b < 0 && b + 256 || b).toString(16)).slice(-2)).join("");
  return { "KEY": key, "Timestamp": t, "SIGN": sign };
}

// Please run this function.
function main() {
  const key = "your api key";
  const secret = "your secret";

  const host = "https://api.gateio.ws";
  const prefix = "/api/v4";
  const url = "/wallet/total_balance";
  const method = "GET";

  const signature = gen_sign_(key, secret, method, prefix + url);
  const headers = { "Accept": "application/json", "Content-Type": "application/json", "muteHttpExceptions": true, ...signature };
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(host + prefix + url, { method, headers });
  console.log(res.getContentText());
}
```

#### Note:

- When I tested the script using the sample variables of `const key = "sample"`, `const secret = "sample"` and `const t = "1234567890.123"` for the python script in the official document and Google Apps Script, the same value of `signature` could be obtained as follows. Both requests are also the same.

  ```
    603899db07ca29e5240de397b8088271b765925ba29a67267b33ad0b076fc31b0cf98d623878d57bf824b58e5336fd74f1cd101e9377816c34fec2acb9358cb2
  ```
- So, when you test the above sample Google Apps Script and if an error occurs, please confirm your variables again. And, please show the error message.

#### References:

- [computeDigest(algorithm, value, charset)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#computedigestalgorithm,-value,-charset)
- [formatString(template, args)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatstringtemplate,-args)
- [computeHmacSignature(algorithm, value, key, charset)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#computehmacsignaturealgorithm,-value,-key,-charset)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)