# Gate exchange can't get orders using app script

Tags: javascript, json, api, google-apps-script

I run script in app script to get data from gate API by GET /spot/orders and work good but, if I change status open to finished return empty.
you can see document from this URL: https://www.gate.io/docs/developers/apiv4/en/#list-orders.

this is code:

```
function orders() {
  const key = "*****";
  const secret = "*****";

  const host = "https://api.gateio.ws";
  const prefix = "/api/v4";
  const url = "/spot/orders";
  const method = "GET";
  const query_param = "currency_pair=BTC_USDT&status=open";

  const signature = gen_sign_(key, secret, method, prefix + url, query_param);
  const headers = { "Accept": "application/json", "Content-Type": "application/json", "muteHttpExceptions": true, ...signature };
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(host + prefix + url + "?" + query_param , { method, headers });
  console.log(res.getContentText());
}
```

This code is work good and give me return of my open orders.

Problem linked by this code:

```
const query_param = "currency_pair=BTC_USDT&status=open";
```

If I change status=open to status=finished.

give me return empty just []

[image]

note: I have orders buy and sell in this pair.

Comment: According to the link you provided, https://www.gate.io/docs/developers/apiv4/en/#list-orders speaks about using the `status=finished` parameter in conjunction with `from` and `to` timestamps for the query. Also, are you using the `side=buy` parameter?

Comment: Yeh I try by side=buy but same problem

Comment: Have you tried to simplify by using `curl` request? If you cannot get any return value from that, then, it may be an issue with the API.

Comment: no I can't try `curl` request because I don't know how to do it. I'm beginner in coding. but I thing the error from platform if `status=finished` not work why if add `status=open` is work. I try to test it in postmap but the gate don't supported in postmap

Comment: same error with this GET: https://www.gate.io/docs/developers/apiv4/en/#list-personal-trading-history return empty []

Comment: I think that your script is correct. And, it seems that `status=finished` can be used. So, about your current situation, I would like to recommend to ask your current situation and your goal for the manager of the API.